# Good use of goto?

Tags: c

I think I may have come across a good use of goto in my code. From when I started programming in C it was driven into me that goto was akin to summoning the devil himself and use of goto should be avoided at all costs. Here is the code

```
/*
    Attempts to get the physical address from a virtual one by 
    1. Consulting the TLB 
    2. Consulting the PageTable
    3. If both fail, request data be read into memory

    Returns the address of the requested virtual address in physical memory
*/
unsigned int getAddress(unsigned int virtualAddress)
{
    const unsigned int pageNumber = getPageNumber(virtualAddress);
    const unsigned int pageOffset = getPageOffset(virtualAddress);

    // first consult the TLB
    int frame = getFrameFromTLB(pageNumber);
    if (frame != SENTINEL)
    {
        TLBHits++;
        goto TLB_HIT;
    }

    // if a TLB miss occurs, consult page table
    frame = getFramePageTable(pageNumber);
    if (frame != SENTINEL)
    {
        goto PAGE_HIT;
    }

    //miss on tlb and page table, page fault occured
    pageFaults++;
    goto PAGE_FAULT;

PAGE_FAULT:
    //page table miss, value not in memory, request physical memory to load value
    frame = loadValueFromBackingStore(pageNumber);

    //update page table with new frame
    insertIntoPageTable(pageNumber, frame);

PAGE_HIT:
    insertIntoTLB(pageNumber, frame);

TLB_HIT:
    return frame * PAGE_SIZE + pageOffset;
}
```

As you can see the code has a cascading execution pattern that a goto seems to model really well. I am wondering is there a clean and similarly sized way to write this without goto? Should that be something I even try to do?

Comment: This looks like Fanuc TP programming

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: This question, along with its answer turns out to be a good demonstration of why gotos should (and can) be avoided most of the time!

Comment: @th33lf I agree, seemed to make sense in the moment but upon further inspection theres always a way around them.

Comment: In error conditions there occasionally is a semi reasonable use of goto, but generally it can and should be avoided most of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
goto PAGE_FAULT;
PAGE_FAULT:
```

This code seems almost like a troll. You can certainly rewrite it to use no `goto`s; all you have to do is un-flip the conditions that you must have flipped when you inserted the `goto`s in the first place. For example:

```
    if (frame != SENTINEL) {
        goto PAGE_HIT;
    }
    pageFaults++;
    frame = loadValueFromBackingStore(pageNumber);
    insertIntoPageTable(pageNumber, frame);
PAGE_HIT:
```

can be rewritten in "structured programming" style as

```
    if (frame == SENTINEL) {
        pageFaults++;
        frame = loadValueFromBackingStore(pageNumber);
        insertIntoPageTable(pageNumber, frame);
    }
```

Your whole function boils down to this:

```
unsigned int getAddress(unsigned int virtualAddress)
{
    const unsigned int pageNumber = getPageNumber(virtualAddress);
    const unsigned int pageOffset = getPageOffset(virtualAddress);

    int frame = getFrameFromTLB(pageNumber);
    if (frame == SENTINEL) {
        frame = getFramePageTable(pageNumber);
        if (frame == SENTINEL) {
            pageFaults += 1;
            frame = loadValueFromBackingStore(pageNumber);
            insertIntoPageTable(pageNumber, frame);
        }
        insertIntoTLB(pageNumber, frame);
    } else {
        TLBHits += 1;
    }
    return frame * PAGE_SIZE + pageOffset;
}
```

Comment: I realize the `goto PAGE_FAULT; PAGE_FAULT:` is redundant, its mostly for readability. Regardless thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The consensus from the never-ending goto debate is pretty much that "yeah there are cases where you can use goto harmlessly when branching non-conditionally downwards, but those cases could as well be written without goto too".

So your code isn't horrible, but it isn't pretty either - it looks like the old "on error goto..." error handling pattern used by BASIC. At any rate, all the jumping around is redundant and makes the code needlessly hard to read.

Since you are updating global variables in several places, you might as well have rewritten the function as this:

```
unsigned int getAddress(unsigned int virtualAddress)
{
  const unsigned int pageNumber = getPageNumber(virtualAddress);
  const unsigned int pageOffset = getPageOffset(virtualAddress);

  if(getFrameFromTLB(pageNumber) != TLB_HIT)
  {
    if(getFramePageTable(pageNumber) != PAGE_HIT)
    {
      //page table miss, value not in memory, request physical memory to load value
      frame = loadValueFromBackingStore(pageNumber);

      //update page table with new frame
      insertIntoPageTable(pageNumber, frame);
    }
  }

  return frame * PAGE_SIZE + pageOffset;
}
```

This assuming that the called functions update the global variables instead, and `TLB_HIT` and so on is some enum with error codes. There are other ways you can rewrite it too.

Comment: Also, not to be underestimated: avoiding goto means you are avoiding having yet another tiresome goto debate.